# (Kotlin)how can i get data from sharedpreferences in another activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have a settings activity and I want to use those settings on other screens I am developing an app to send balance for phones, normally the one who makes these sales must enter a series of codes on his sales phone, what I want is to save that annoyance to the vendor and have the codes fixed but there is a pin that is unique to each vendor which in my application should enter (your vendor pin) only once in settings and then not worry about anything

[This is the settings Activity u have to enter your pin in that EditText and then the app have to remember the pin at each transaction u do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiaKJ.jpg)

```
override fun onCreatelsavedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstance5tate) 
        
        setContentView(R. Layout.activity_main) 
        
        
        loadData()
        
        
        savebutton. setonClicklistener (){saveData() }
      
    }
                                           
     
    private fun loadData (){ 
            
            val sharePref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
            
            val mydata = sharePref.getString( key: "mydata", defValue: "") 
            
            dataEditText.setText (dato)
    }
            
    private fun saveData(){ 
            
         sharePref = getPreferences (Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            
         with(sharePref.edit()){
           putString("pin", dataEditText.text.tostring())
           commit() ^with
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `getSharedPreferences`
- Because `getPreferences`: use only one shared preference file for the activity.
- `getSharedPreferences`: use this if you need multiple shared preference files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter. You can call this from any Context in your app.

```kotlin
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key),
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
```

Comment: thanks bro, now it works fine, you really helped me

Comment: then you should approve his answer mate so other people can see it

Answer (score 0):

1.Create Class

class SharedPreference(val context: Context) {
private val PREFS_NAME = "kotlincodes"
val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

```
fun save(KEY_NAME: String, text: String) {
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, text)
    editor!!.commit()
}

fun save(KEY_NAME: String, value: Int) {
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putInt(KEY_NAME, value)
    editor.commit()
}

fun save(KEY_NAME: String, status: Boolean) {
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_NAME, status!!)
    editor.commit()
}

fun getValueString(KEY_NAME: String): String? {
    return sharedPref.getString(KEY_NAME, null)
}

fun getValueInt(KEY_NAME: String): Int {
    return sharedPref.getInt(KEY_NAME, 0)
}

fun getValueBoolien(KEY_NAME: String, defaultValue: Boolean): Boolean {
    return sharedPref.getBoolean(KEY_NAME, defaultValue)
}

fun clearSharedPreference() {
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    //sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor.clear()
    editor.commit()
}

fun removeValue(KEY_NAME: String) {
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.remove(KEY_NAME)
    editor.commit()
}
```

}